# How to run a java program upon compilation of class

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide, scala-macros

I have a java jar I want to invoke when a class is compiled using the Eclipse IDE :

```
java -jar myjar.jar args1 args2
```

Is there a java lib I can use for this or perhaps use a Scala macro ?

Comment: Which build system or IDE are you using? If you are using the command line you can create a shell script to compile and run your JAR

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I'm using Eclipse

Comment: What do you mean by "when a class is compiled"? Do you want to intercept when Eclipse compiles something?

Comment: @kutschkem yes thats correct

Answer (score 1):

you can right click your project select properties / builders / new. this will add an external program to be run. after project compilation. (it will only be once per compile, not once per compilation unit, which is what i think you are referring to). however its easy enough to keep track of that by your external program, and run something for every updated compilation unit (or newly generated class file)

Comment: another option is to run a compilation server separate from eclipse (or as an external tool), use java/nio/file/WatchService for updated .class files that you can then modify.